# Convert rows To Column SQL Server

Tags: sql, pivot

I have Below Sample Table

```
month   year    budget_Amt   Actual_Amt
feb     2017      25           30
mar     2016      10           5
apr     2016      50           15
```

My Output should be like this:

```
month year Budget_Amt Actual_amt Budget_Amt1 Actual_amt1 Budget_Amt2 Actual_Amt2   
Feb   2017    25          30          null          null        null      null   
mar   2016    null      null          10            5          null      null  
apr   2016    null      null         null          null        50        15
```

What Would be Query in Sql?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server (as the title suggests) or MySQL (as the tag suggested)?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the 1,118 other results that are returned when you search for ["Convert rows To Column SQL Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Convert+rows+To+Column+SQL+Server) on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

This is not done using a pivot, but it does gets the desired result. And you dont have to declare the column names, it can have dynamic columns. Its tested with above scenario.

```
create table #testdata(id int ,month varchar(10),   year int,    budget_Amt int null,   Actual_Amt int null)

insert into #testdata(id, month ,  year,    budget_Amt,   Actual_Amt)
values(1,'feb',     2017,      25,           30),
(2, 'mar',     2016,      10,           5),
(3, 'apr',     2016,      50,           15)

declare @count int
declare @budget_Amt varchar(500) = ''
declare @Actual_Amt varchar(500) = ''

select @count = COUNT(*) from #testdata
declare @i int = 0
while @i < @count
begin
    if(@i = 0)
    begin
        select @budget_Amt = 'budget_Amt' + ' int null, '
        select @Actual_Amt = 'Actual_Amt' + ' int null, '
        set @i = @i + 1
    end
    else
    begin
    set @i = @i + 1
    if(@i = @count)
    begin
    select @budget_Amt = @budget_Amt + 'budget_Amt' + convert(varchar(10),@i-1) + ' int null '
    select @Actual_Amt = @Actual_Amt + 'Actual_Amt' + convert(varchar(10),@i-1) + ' int null '
    end
    else
    begin
    select @budget_Amt = @budget_Amt + 'budget_Amt' + convert(varchar(10),@i-1) + ' int null, '
    select @Actual_Amt = @Actual_Amt + 'Actual_Amt' + convert(varchar(10),@i-1) + ' int null, '
    end end
end

declare @createQuery as nvarchar(500) set @createQuery = 'create table ##temp(month varchar(10),   year int,' +  @budget_Amt + ',' + @Actual_Amt + ')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @createQuery 
select @createQuery declare @insert nvarchar(max) = 'insert into ##temp(month, year,'
declare @tempInsert nvarchar(MAX)
set @i = 0
while @i < @count
begin
    if(@i = 0)
    begin
select @tempInsert = @insert + 'budget_Amt,Actual_Amt) select month, year,budget_Amt,Actual_Amt from #testdata where id = ' +convert(varchar(10),@i+1)
        select @tempInsert EXECUTE sp_executesql @tempInsert 
        set @i = @i + 1
    end
    else
    begin
    set @i = @i + 1

select @tempInsert = @insert + 'budget_Amt' + convert(varchar(10),@i-1) + ',Actual_Amt' + convert(varchar(10),@i-1) + ') select month, year,budget_Amt,Actual_Amt from #testdata where id = ' +convert(varchar(10),@i)
    select @tempInsert    EXECUTE sp_executesql @tempInsert
     end
end
select * from ##temp
drop table #testdata, ##temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cross join` two time on your table
Please try this:

```
select top 1 a.id, a.month,a.year,a.budget_Amt,a.Actual_Amt, null 
budget_Amt1,null Actual_Amt1,null budget_Amt2,null Actual_Amt2  from  
SampleTable a,  SampleTable b,  SampleTable c
union
select top 1 b.id, b.month,b.year,null budget_Amt,null Actual_Amt, 
b.budget_Amt,b.Actual_Amt,null budget_Amt2,null Actual_Amt2 from  
SampleTable a,  SampleTable b,  SampleTable c
where b.id>a.id
union
select top 1 c.id, c.month,c.year,null budget_Amt,null Actual_Amt, 
null,null,c.budget_Amt,c.Actual_Amt from  SampleTable a,  SampleTable b,  
SampleTable c
where c.id>b.id+a.id
order by id
```

I hope this hepls